# in sql how to find lowest and highest value

Tags: sql, union

I have two tables and I want to write a query which wil give the highest and lowest value I am doing like this way but its shows ''some error near union' ....(using union is mand.)

```
select TOP 1  od.productid,od.unitprice,totalprice=(od.unitprice-od.discount) from orderdetails od
inner join
orders o
on od.orderid=o.orderid
where o.orderdate between '10/7/1997' and '10/14/1997'
order by totalprice asc

union  

select TOP 1 od.productid,od.unitprice,totalprice=(od.unitprice-od.discount) from orderdetails od
inner join
orders o
on od.orderid=o.orderid
where o.orderdate between '10/7/1997' and '10/14/1997'
order by totalprice asc
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [**What have you tried?**](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume that you are using Sql Server.

You cannot have an `ORDER BY` as part of the first select part of the union.

You need to use sub selects if you wish to use order by.

Something like

```
DECLARe @TABLE  TABLE(
        Val VARCHAR(20)
)

SELECT  *
FROM    (
            SELECT  TOP 1
                    Val
            FROM    @TABLE
            ORDER BY val
        ) minVal
UNION 
SELECT  *
FROM    (
            SELECT  TOP 1
                    Val
            FROM    @TABLE
            ORDER BY val DESC
        ) maxVal
```

Comment: thanks a lot u have solved my prob the solution is 


SELECT  *
FROM    (select TOP 1  od.productid,od.unitprice,totalprice=(od.unitprice-od.discount) from orderdetails od
inner join
orders o
on od.orderid=o.orderid
where o.orderdate between '10/7/1997' and '10/14/1997'
order by totalprice asc
        ) maxvalue
UNION 
SELECT  *
FROM    (
            select TOP 1  od.productid,od.unitprice,totalprice=(od.unitprice-od.discount) from orderdetails od
inner join
orders o
on od.orderid=o.orderid
where o.orderdate between '10/7/1997' and '10/14/1997'
order by totalprice desc
        )minvalue